Tensorflow can't find available GPUs (win11)
I have a pretty common issue: tensorflow framework can't recognize available GPUs on my laptop.
When i try to list available GPUs in VS Code using Python (v3.11.0):
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print("Built with CUDA:", tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print("Built with GPU device support:", tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support())

output: 
Num GPUs Available: 0
Built with CUDA: False
Built with GPU device support: False

Laptop specs:

System: Windows 11 Pro (23H2)
GPU: GeForce GTX 1660Ti 6Gb
CPU: Intel Core i7 9750h

What i've done before:

Download Tensorflow framework (2.16.1) via pip

pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]


Updated NVIDIA driver (v560.70)
Downloaded NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit (CUDA v12.3)
Downloaded cuDNN driver (v8.9) and paste files from bin, lib, include to appropriate folders in CUDA root path
Manually added environment variables in Windows system properties (Path, CUDA_PATH, CUDA_HOME)
Env variables config
Added custom graphic settings to VS Code IDE Settings -> System -> Display -> Graphics
Checked: does the system detect the video card using cmd: nvidia-smi terminal output
Checked drivers compatibility (i guess everything ok)
Restart system

Hope we'll find the solution :), if you have specific questions, please ask

There is no native GPU acceleration in Tensorflow after 2.10. Please take the time to read the release notes

TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPUs on native-Windows. If you need to run on a Windows system with a newer version of TensorFlow you'll need to set up WSL2. Here's the user guide from Nvidia on setting up WSL2 for Cuda: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Thank you for the answer, i'll check with TF 2.10 now
